# setTimeout not working for div to load or anchor

Tags: javascript

trying to load div after 30 second and code is very simple and ideally it should work. i want to load div content after 30 second so i am trying to click one dummy anchor. i know we can directly load div with settimeout without dummy anchor but it was not working so i tried trigger. i have tried delay and all other function. jquery is already loaded. because when i click them manually they work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#999').trigger('click');
  }, 5000);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#popup_chrome" class="popup_chrome" id="999">Chrome Extension</a>
<div id="popup_chrome" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Download Chrome Extension</h2><br>
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
      <br /><a href="dfdfd" target="_blank" class="myButton_sub">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a template to hold the popup and then populate some container with the template contents upon timeout:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#container').html($('#popup_content').html());
  }, 4000);
});
```

```css
#popup_chrome {
  margin: 15px;
  width: 50vw;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5>Wait for it...</h5>
<div id="container"></div>
<template id="popup_content">
<div id="popup_chrome" class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Download Chrome Extension</h2><br>
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
      <br /><a href="dfdfd" target="_blank" class="myButton_sub">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Click "Run code snippet" it works. You provide a link with no explanation of "not working" and expect me to guess? imagine? the issue?  I'm trying to help, but if you don't provide any clue about what "not working" means, helping is impossible.

Comment: sorry. but i am also clueless. my code also works fine when i click manually in link and popup opens just fine. so i am also trying to figure out what is happening exactly. will update. sorry i did not mean link only. i am struggling sorry again and thanks for taking time to help. u guys are awesome

Comment: You can start by explaining: _my code also works fine when i click manually in link and popup opens just fine._ Do you mean when you click the anchor tag for "Extension" that navigates away to the Chrome store? or some other "link" on that page?

Comment: sorry for delay. when u click chrome extension from dropdown last item one popup opens. same thing i want to do automatically after 30 second https://imgur.com/LoY2Qnt